# How to calculate price after notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an e-commerce app. Currently, I'm creating add-to-cart fragment. So, I've managed to add the item to cart and display in CartFragment. But the problem is, when a product is deleted then notifyDataSetChanged() and all checkbox must checked, the price is increases. I want when a product is deleted, then total of all prices is calculated.

Before a product is deleted :

[image: 1]

After a product is deleted :

[image: 2]

My adapter code :

```
    int total_all_item;

    if (price_after_discount != 0) {
        productCart.setTotalPrice(price_after_discount);
        String price = (String.format("Rp%,d", productList.get(position).getPriceAfterDiscount())).replace(",", ".");
        productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(productList.get(position).getPriceAfterDiscount());
        productList.get(position).setTotalAllProduct(productList.get(position).getPriceAfterDiscount());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(price);
    } else {
        productCart.setTotalPrice(price_reguler);
        String price = (String.format("Rp%,d", productList.get(position).getPriceRegular())).replace(",", ".");
        productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(productList.get(position).getPriceRegular());
        productList.get(position).setTotalAllProduct(productList.get(position).getPriceRegular());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(price);
    }

    holder.ibDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteCartList(context, qty, product_id, notes, dataItemCart, productCart, position);
        }
    });

    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
        int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();

        if (currentQty > 0) {
            total_all_item += productList.get(position).getFinalPrice() * currentQty;
            listener.onItemCheck(dataItemCart, productCart, dataItemCheckoutList, productCheckoutList);
            listener.setTotalPrice(total_all_item);

            dataItemCheckout.setId(dataItemCartList.get(position).getId());
            dataItemCheckout.setCurrentPrice(dataItemCartList.get(position).getCurrentPrice());
            dataItemCheckout.setLastPrice(dataItemCartList.get(position).getLastPrice());
            dataItemCheckout.setQuantity(dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity());
            dataItemCheckout.setNotes(dataItemCartList.get(position).getNotes());

            dataItemCheckoutList.add(dataItemCheckout);

            productCheckout.setId(productList.get(position).getId());
            productCheckout.setImage(productList.get(position).getImage());
            productCheckout.setName(productList.get(position).getName());
            productCheckout.setPriceAfterDiscount(productList.get(position).getPriceAfterDiscount());
            productCheckout.setPriceRegular(productList.get(position).getPriceRegular());

            productCheckoutList.add(productCheckout);

            listener.sendData(dataItemCheckout, productCheckout, dataItemCart, productCart, dataItemCheckoutList, productCheckoutList, dataItemCartList, productList, holder.checkBox.isChecked());
        }
    }
```

Code for deleting a product :

```
private void deleteCartList(final Context context, int qty, int product_id, String notes, final DataItemCart dataItemCart, final Product productCart, final int position) {
    ResponseDeleteCart model = new ResponseDeleteCart(
            qty,
            notes,
            product_id
    );

    Call<JsonObject> categoryCall = baseApiService.deleteCartlist(model);
    categoryCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse :" + response.body().toString());

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                        String message = "Item berhasil dihapus";

                        dataItemCartList.remove(dataItemCart);
                        productList.remove(productCart);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);

                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        String message = "Item gagal dihapus";

                        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "message : " + jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Maaf, terjadi kesalahan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure :" + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is your adapter code your showing for your `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: @COYG correct, code from my adapter is code in `onBindViewHolder` method